# How to allow remote image src URLs in Apache Cordova app

Tags: cordova, phonegap, content-security-policy

I'm migrating create-react-app to Apache Cordova. My relative URLs to static images are working. Ex: `./images/path/to/file.jpeg`

But in the iOS simulator I can't reference remote image sources in an S3 bucket. Ex: `//s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bla/bla/bla/8CCE-B64FD7247407.jpeg?1617374606`

I think this is a security configuration issue, but I'm not sure. This is what is currently in my config.xml file:

```
    <access origin="*" allows-local-networking='true' />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <allow-intent href="*" />
    </platform>
```

I currently have no `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="...">` in my index.html file.

What am I doing wrong?

**Updates 1&2**

I tried updating my config.xml file to include:

```
<allow-intent href="//:*/*" />
<access origin='*' allows-arbitrary-loads-for-media='true' allows-arbitrary-loads-in-web-content='true' allows-local-networking='true' />
```

Unfortunately this didn't work.

Like @DaveAlden suggested, it looks like this might be a CSP problem...

My original index.html file does not include the `Content-Security-Policy` meta tag at all, but when I run the cordova app in the browser and view the source. This is what I see:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;">
```

Now I think my question is: **Where is that CSP coming from? And, how do I modify it?**

For a moment I was scratching my head as to why remote images are working in the browser because my understanding is that `img-src 'self'` should disallow `<img src="//:bla-bla.amazonaws.com/bla/bla" />`. I think part of the explanation is that when I use the dev tools to inspect the `<head>` of the document, I see a *different* CSP tag than when I view source.
[image]
This CSP matches what I currently have in my index.html file before running `cordova run ...`.

It *seems* like somehow Cordova is using a different, default CSP for iOS but somehow overriding it in the browser. I'm confused.

** Update 3**

I searched the files of my project and I discovered that the mysterious CSP (that I'm seeing in the browser) matches the default "template" policy listed on the [cordova-plugin-whitelist README](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist/blob/master/README.md#content-security-policy). <-- This suggests to me that my src index.html isn't getting used at all, and Cordova is falling back to an internal default.

Comment: check the CSP: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/guide/appdev/allowlist/#content-security-policy-csp

Comment: @DaveAlden I currently have no CSP meta tag in my index.html. I thought this results in maximum permissiveness. Is that incorrect?

Comment: @DaveAlden I updated the questions with more clues related to CSP. It looks like it's getting mysteriously injected somehow...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Rrrrrrrr... I discovered that I can [debug the iOS simulator using Safari](https://technikales.com/how-to-debug-websites-on-ios-and-ipados-devices-simulators-with-the-safari-browser/) and the CSP looks correct! I double-checked this in Safari and Chrome and they both show the correct CSP as well. So it appears that Firefox is showing something confusing when I click "View source" (I still can't explain this part) but this was a distraction from the real issue...

iOS is trying to request the remote image file with an incorrect `file://` prefix. I think this is connected to the fact that the AWS URLs don't specify the protocol. Ex: `//s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bla/bla/...`

The browsers seem to handle this just fine. But in the iOS simulator, it seems to think it's a local file. Notice that it has a `file://` prefix.

I changed the API to return `https://` and now it works in the simulator.

[image]

Comment: Yeah don't use firefox to build Android app, use Chrome + Safari for iOS

Comment: @Eric Can you elaborate on that tip? I was using Firefox to test in the browser. Is there something specific about Firefox and Cordova apps?

Comment: It is preferable to test your application on Safari or Chrome because they are the closest browsers to the technology used by Cordova.
For iOS, Cordova now uses WKWebView which is based on the Safari engine.
For Android, Cordova uses WebKit which was the basis of Chrome until 2013. Today chrome remains closer to Webkit than Firefox which uses Gecko since 1998. (And there is also Quantum but I did not get interested in it)

WebKit is currently the rendering engine of Safari, so it's the best browser to have a "faithful" rendering to the Cordova application.

Comment: Source | IOS : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview | Android : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/package-summary | https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSP from

```
img-src 'self'
```

to

```
img-src *
```

Comment: Right. My question is how can I achieve that? Cordova seems to be injecting it's own CSP rules that are overriding the ones I try to set.

Comment: I do not have the issue here when setting it at a meta in my index.html file, Cordova does not mess with it ...